# Prevent lockups from badly behaving browser tab?

Tags: firefox, desktop, iceweasel

I've been having some issues on my desktop. Debian 8. Sometimes the system becomes completely unresponsive, for up to fifteen minutes at a time. This almost always happens when I'm running a browser, usually iceweasel, and usually it's after clicking on a link. It is also completely without warning, it happens immediately. I'm blaming whatever site is trying to load. However, the fact that my desktop becomes completely unusable is unacceptable. I usually have to ssh into my system and issue a "killall -9 iceweasel". Is there any way I can prevent these kinds of lockups?

Thanks!

Comment: When you ssh into your system, did you use `top` and `free -m` to check it is really the Iceweasel the problem? Do you run out of memory?
Does it happen with other browsers?

Comment: Did you have a system/kernel/process mgmt solution, or a iceweasel or both in mind "any way", you say? With an extension like *noscript* you might have blocked initial javascript/active content which I guess to be a likely suspect

Comment: can you give more details? free, px uax, top, uptime. Have your tried to ran iceweasel from the command line to see what errors does it report? This kind of programs use up a lot RAM, ran a memtest, it could be some bad RAM.

Comment: Not sure about preventing, but instead of `ssh`-ing into your system, you can use `<CTRL>`+`<ALT>`+`<F2>` to switch to another tty. Then, log in and `kill` as before.

Comment: There's no possible way answering this without further details:

1. htop and see the memory usage for the browser
2. free -m, as mentioned above
3. strace of the process would also be useful
4. information regarding the graphic manager used on this Debian

Answer (score 1):

In my case with similar symptoms one (or all) of these steps helped:

- Update *Iceweasel*
- Update *Pipelight*
- Re-enable plugins by `pipelight-plugin --enable pluginname`. Use `pipelight-plugin --help` to get a list of available plugins.
- Restart *Iceweasel* if it was running during the previous step.

*Pipelight* allows you to run Windows plugins in Linux browsers, particularly *Silverlight* and *Flash Player*. I had to install it to be able to watch videos on demand. Further details on it: http://pipelight.net/cms/about.html